How to display a message while a new Blazor WASM app version is downloading
I have a large Blazor WASM PWA app.  After publishing a new version (via Azure App Services), the new version takes quite awhile to download before the app gets past my "Please wait..." message in index.html which I put there for a normal startup delay.  Is there a way to tell (in index.html or somewhere else) when a new version is downloading so that I can display a different message during this long delay.

A PWA should download the new updates in the background using a service worker - there should not be any delay on the current instance loading unless it has a problem.

Thanks.  I converted my app to PWA awhile ago using instructions I found somewhere and recall reading what you are saying.  As I also recall, the documentation said that the app had to be run twice to get the new version...the 1st time triggers the download and the 2nd runs it.  I must have done something wrong when converting to PWA.  I'll have to double-check everything.
